# Do you extract the call to determine the length of an array/string from the for-header?

Tags: language-agnostic, for-loop, complexity-theory

I've recently noticed a coworker of mine doing

```
int len = foo.length();
for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    doStuff(foo[i]);
```

I'm aware that this was considered good practice in C, where strlen() ran in O(length_of_string). But I'd expect newer languages (say, Java or Python) to store the length of the String alongside the characters, thus allowing length() to run in O(1). I usually write:

```
for (int i = 0; i < foo.length(); ++i)
    doStuff(foo[i]);
```

Saving a line of code. But my Co-Worker got me wondering.... is this really good practice, or is it unreasonable to expect the O(1) behaviour?

(As a related question: can't modern compilers extract the strlen() call from inside the for-header automatically these days?)

Answer (score 1):

These statements are actually two different statements.

```
int len = foo.length(); // Will run once
for (int i = 0; i<len;++i)
```

Here `i<len` will be checked every loop, len is just a variable that can be read though.

```
for (int i = 0; i < foo.length(); ++i)
```

Here `i < foo.length()` contains a function call, and since the length of `foo` can change within the loop itself (You could e.g. strip characters off of `foo` instead of incrementing `i`) the function `foo.length()` will be called every iteration.

There are some languages in which foo might be a constant and foo.length() could be optimised out by the compiler, but it's better to be save than sorry.

Additionally some languages might allow something like this:

```
for (int i=0, len=foo.length();i<len;++i)
```

which still saves you the line.

Comment: I'm aware of the slight semantic difference. But the basic question was if it makes sense to put the length()-call in front of the header for basic data structures like strings and arrays. I don't think it does, as I would expect length() to be of O(1) anyways.
(And yes, I'm aware that for Lists or Trees or whatever I shouldn't expect O(1), hence I limit myself to arrays & strings).

Comment: If you take my last line of code and what your co-worker wrote, there shouldn't really be any difference or I wouldn't know the answer. Comparing the code that you gave to that of your co-worker's is different however because in your code `foo.length()` is called every iteration, whereas your co-worker's `foo.length()` is only called once.

Answer (score 0):

First, call the function foo.length() each iteration of the loop in any case would require more resources than using a temporary variable to store result of the call foo.length().

Furthermore, the use of your code may cause errors when refactoring code. For example, this cycle will never end:

```
for (int i = 0; i < foo.length(); ++i)
{
    doStuff(foo[i]);

    // few line of code, written another man
    doWork(foo); // Passing by reference
}

void doWork(Foo fooObj)
{
    // some work

    fooObj.Add(new SomeObject());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't very language agnostic. It depends on how smart is the compiler. If you can explicitly state that the length is constant, the whole loop can be inlined, so no tests happen at all. When it comes to Java, I would bet compiler can get pretty smart, so you don't have to be explicit that much. You are right about java.lang.String precomputing its length. When it comes to complexity, it is practical to define what are the important operations you are counting. Strictly speaking on a Turing machine you have to be O(n) in order to find the end ("$") of the input.